# Alternatives to copy constructors and assignments?

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor

I want to use a variable as a global but the class the variable belongs to disallows assignments and copy constructors.  The class is too complex for me to go in and make changes at my current skill level. The constructor requires a user input, so the variable cannot be defined in the .h file. Do you guys with more experience know a work around aside from the use of pointers or references.

Now assuming the solution is to use a pointer or reference, how do I pass pointers/references to event handler functions.

Comment: Do you have access to TR1 or C++11?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Not sure if I'm understanding the problem correctly but I would create a wrapper class like

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper<T>
{
  T the_variable_you_wanted;
  Wrapper<T>(const Wrapper<T>&) = delete;
  Wrapper<T>& operator=(const Wrapper<T>&) = delete;
}
```